# Use of 'this' in closure

Tags: jquery, closures, this

I'm just curious... how am I supposed to use 'this' within a jQuery function?

For example, if I have some code like this...

```
    headEl.find("form.blog-search input").focus(function() {
        $(this).next("span").animate({opacity:1}, 200);
    })
```

It works fine, however when linting I get the warning of "**Use of '*this*' in closure**".

Is this something I should just ignore, or is there something I can do to not only solve the warning, but improve my code?

**Update:**

Based on Kevin B's comment below, I changed up the code to

```
    headEl.find("form.blog-search input").on('focus', function(event) {
        $(event.target).next("span").animate({opacity:1}, 200);
    })
```

Which works as expected... now I'm just curious, what are the downsides to this method and when should it be used in favor of `this` or vice-versa?

Comment: Nope, seems fine to me !

Comment: did you try `.on('focus', function() { ...` (but that would still use `this` in a closure ?)

Comment: I guess you could accept the event parameter and use `event.target`, but that could have other issues because it isn't always the same as `this` (though in this case it is). I would ignore the warning.

Comment: The warning lets you know that `this` might not be what you expect. Here, though, `this` is exactly what you need, and you seem to use it correctly. Possibly you could try using a non-anonymous function and move it outside of whatever containing function it's currently in, like `.focus(focusHandler)` (and then define the `focusHandler` function not inside another function).

Comment: If I recall correctly, 'this' is evaluated when the function is invoked. Within a closure, this means that things can happen that you don't expect. In the typical case if you want access to the values associated with 'this' when the function is defined, you can say 'var closure = this;' and then use 'closure' instead of 'this'.

Comment: Your update, while a good question, is decidedly not the same question. I would advise posting a new question so we don't get all kinds of muddled answers that only address half the question. (And, more importantly, it will much easier for future readers to digest the answsers.)

Comment: The [code that generates the warning](https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9/blob/master/plugins-client/ext.jslanguage/scope_analyzer.js#L491) in Cloud9 appears to naively check for th epresence of "`this`" inside of functions-within-functions.

Comment: Whoa, you figured out I was using C9?

Comment: A small note of caution - substituting `event.target` for `this` will be OK in most circumstances but not all. Where an event is delegated, then `event.target` and `this`, inside an event handler, will refer to different DOM elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say ignore jslint personally.  If you really wanted to get rid of the warning you could probably do this:

```
headEl.find("form.blog-search input").focus(function(e) {
    $(e.currentTarget).next("span").animate({opacity:1}, 200);
})
```

The function passed to `focus` gets passed the event object.

http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/

Comment: The lint warning is just wrong - ignore it.  That should be the recommendation.  Not changing to a less efficient way of coding.

Comment: @jfriend00  Agreed, which is why I started the answer with "ignore it".  But I don't see it as particularly less efficient.  I do find it less readable, which is reason enough to ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue which your use of `this` in this particular closure.

The warning is probably because sometimes people expect the value of `this` to be the same as it was outside the closure and that is often not the case.

In your particular case you are using it correctly as the event system sets `this` to be the object that triggered the event.

For example, people often do an ajax call and expect the value of `this` to be the same inside the success handler as it was when the ajax call was made, but that is usually not the case.